# Creating an interactive map with CSS

Tags: css, dictionary

Based on the design below, is it possible to create the map just using CSS? If so, how?

So as you can see, when you hover over a state the name will appear and change the color of the state. On clicking it will info below the map per state.

UPDATE 1:
Can it be done using absolute positioning, z-index and hover states on a button?

UPDATE 2:
With a slight tweak to the design, would it be possible to have a flat image for the map and plotting dot's on it for each state that would include a hover (using the same tab style as the image example)? Each dot being an image. Am I right in saying that the complication of the design is to highlight the right area when hovered? Therefore, just having a dot would solve it right?

Comment: Because the images are not square - I believe you can not do it using css only. You should use flash or something.

Comment: This is trivial in SVG, but not in HTML+CSS alone.

Comment: @Joey Are you saying it can't be done then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was interested in this too and found this example (USA) [MAP](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/us%28.html#map) if you look into the source code there is area for each state that look like `<area onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide()" onclick="fform.tg.checked=false;togl()" shape="poly" coords="179,33,174,66,230,67,225,35,179,33,179,33" href="us-nd.html">`. You can read more about  and  tags in [W3C link](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp). I think its the only way how to do this without flash or something... But it cant be done without a little JS. To get the coords, I would asume you just open your image in some editor that shows coords(gimp or something) and manually find them out...

Comment: I've added an update to my question. Would having dots on a flat map solve the problem? Am I right in saying the complication is highlighting the right area when hovered?

Comment: I think i t would solve the problem, but would it be nice? I doubt it.. If you are willing to experiment with js a little, I would recommend to try [THIS](http://www.iamjacksdesign.com/blog/add-hover-effects-to-your-image-maps/) to get working.

Comment: That's exactly what I want!! The thing I don't get is what image do I start with?

Comment: Found the map, struggling to change the color scheme (ie the highlights, borders etc).

Comment: Image choice is on you, just find some suitable image, get coordinates from it, create clickable map using those coordinates and than apply that JS. I haven't tried it myself but it looks pretty easy... let me know if you got that working ;)

Comment: I think I've got it figured now. The only part I don't get  is getting the coordinates of an image, how would I do that?

Comment: when i did this few years ago, i just opened the image in graphic editor(i used photoshop but any free editor which shows coordinates of cursor will be fine) and then moved cursor to one corner of desired area(one corner of one state on the map), writed down his coordinates, move cursor to another corner and so on till you have all corners of all areas on map... its a lot of boring work :-). Then just create that map using those coordinates in <area> tags

Answer (score 0):

No. If it had rectangular shapes yes but with a lot of work.

You really need javascript on this one.

Comment: Sigh, I thought that might be the case. My Javascript isn't great either so is there any tutorials or anything to follow? Thanks

Comment: Can it be done using absolute positioning, z-index and hover states on a button do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a Javascript mapping library - www.openlayers.org is the market leader (and free and open source).

You get your US state map in the right format (GML for example) then you can pretty much cut n paste from one of the openlayers examples. Hovering and clicking are handled by event functions. They can then do things like updating your info box below the map.

Note that if you want Alaska and Hawaii as in the picture and all you can find is a geographic state map, you might have to use a GIS to shift the features around. Quantum GIS is a free and open-source GIS that can do this for you. Help for that can be found on gis.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I've added an update to my question. Would having dots on a flat map solve the problem? Am I right in saying the complication is highlighting the right area when hovered?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use javascript, jQuery more specifically, here is a nice plug-in/tutorial on how to do what it seems like you'd like to. http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map.html. It won't do the states exactly, but it will allow you to drop pins and such.

**Update:** This seems to be exactly what you're looking for: http://playground.mobily.pl/tutorials/building-an-interactive-map-with-raphael.html. It includes a rather indepth tutorial as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another interactive US map I found myself: http://www.fla-shop.com/products/html5/united-states/us/ It is purely javascript with customizable popups.